# How can I simulate the circuit with floating node in Orcad simulation?

Tags: orcad, floating

I simulated to test 4n25 optocoupler. 
6 pin in 4n25 is base of output transistor. 
According to google, 6 pin can be not connect pin (NC) because input LED 
generate the base signal.

Orcad simulation alerts the 6 pin don't remain as floating node, 
but I want to place this pin as floating node.

Are there any other solution to do this?

Comment: Connect it to ground via 1 Gohm.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have some connection to Spice ground on the phototransistor side and you're only getting it complaining about the base connection, you can connect the base to the emitter via a very high value resistor (eg. 1G). You can't have parts of your circuit (such as the secondary of a transformer) just floating around.

When this pin is used, it's typically connected to the emitter by a much lower value resistor (perhaps 100K), which decreases the sensitivity but increases the speed.